# Dockerfile with ARG to FROM

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm trying to use [`nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged`](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx-unprivileged/blob/main/Dockerfile-debian.template) with a different uid and gid for the nginx workers. For this I'm supplying the UID and GID docker parameters, but they seem to be overwritten by the default ones. Here's two variations I tried:

Dockerfile

```
ARG UID=998
ARG GID=998

# This image allows from parameterized UID/GID
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.21.4
```

command: `docker build --tag nginx-uids .`

and

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.21.4
```

command:  docker build --tag nginx-uids --build-arg UID=998 .

The latter even errors with: `[Warning] One or more build-args [UID] were not consumed`, which indicates that it does not use the UID.

There must be something I'm missing, but I cannot figure out what it is. Thanks!

Comment: This question is flagged `docker-multi-stage-build` but actually it’s not. It’s a regular build, based on another image, but it’s different from a multi-stage build.

Answer (score 3):

`UID` and `GID` are here just `arguments` for the image when building it. This appears to not being used.

Said differently, the `ARG` are used when building the image, not reusing the image.

Your cannot use the `--user` argument of `docker run` because the image files will be owned by `UID=101` and `GID=101` based on the image Dockerfile content.
But it’s ok, it will already run with that user and not root.

Comment: I was under the understanding that with ARG I could influence the parameter in `FROM` as well. Does that only work if I use the source Dockerfile? It kind of misses the point if being there then imho. I'm not looking for `--user` by the way.

Comment: Anything that's run in a Dockerfile is compiled into the image.  You're asking to pick up an already-built image, but then change one of its build-time parameters; that flow doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidMaze so how would I use the feature? Build a new image from the original source Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that a `FROM` cannot be influenced with `ARGS`, since the layers are built already. To answer my own question: to make ARGS work I could have used:

`docker build -t nginxinc/docker-nginx-unprivileged  --build-arg UID=998 --build-arg GID=999 'https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx-unprivileged.git#main:stable/debian'`

and then build from that image.

I chose to edit the user instead from the Dockerfile (this approach will not work for docker-nginx-unprivileged, since the user there is already running the nginx master process).

```
FROM nginx:1.21.4

RUN usermod -u 998 -o nginx && groupmod -g 999 -o nginx
```